# Unable to edit any cell within kendo grid table in IE using selenium webdriver

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, kendo-grid, dropdown

I am trying to edit a row within kendo grid. My code is

```
 IList <IWebElement> cellInGrid = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//td[@role='gridcell']"));
```

Click on cell to make the cell editable

```
cellInGrid[index].Click();
```

Say the editable cell is a dropdown cell. So click on the cell again to open the dropdown list

```
cellInGrid[index].Click();
```

Above code works fine in Chrome. But does not work in IE browser. In IE click happens on cell but it does not make the cell editable. So I look into DOM and observe that when user click on the cell then a class k-state-focused appears within the td i.e

```
<td class = "left k-state-focused" role ="gridcell" >fieldValue</td>
```

In chrome browser k-state-focused disappears quickly and replaced by the class k-edit-cell but in IE some times k-state-focused does not disappeared. When I test it manually in IE browser Then it is random issue and it solved after clicking on multiple times. So I changed the code in following way

```
cellInGrid[index].Click();
int numberOfClicks = 0;
while(!cellInGrid[index].GetAttribute("class").Contains("k-edit-cell"))
{
cellInGrid[index].Click();
Thread.Sleep(500)
numberOfClicks++;
if(numberOfClicks >=1000)
break;
}
```

Now clicks on cell 1000 times but never the cell goes to in edit mode, k-state-focused always visible when I tried the clicks using selenium. Can any one help me on this issue?